# Access Form switches unintentionally between Datasets

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am rather new to coding an Access Application and I have a rather strange error I do not seem to be able to resolve.

I have multiple Forms which are used to write data to some tables. Basically one Form per table.

Mostly the forms are just used to show a selection of the data in the tables. To make sure that noone accidentally alters some data you have to press the button "alter" first, which unlocks the fields to alter the dataset. In one form, however, when you ppress the alter button it switches the dataset. I have one column which is an automated ID which serves as a primary key to distinguish the data from one another.
So when I am debugging the issue and print this ID (`Debug.Print Forms(formName).Controls("ID")`) it returns the ID of the data that I want to alter, but as soon as I access the data and change one field (`Forms(formName).Controls("Column1") = "foo"`) and print the ID again the ID switched to a completely different dataset.
I have absolutely no clue how that could happen. There is no other code being processed in between. I have googled for multiple hours but have not found anything in this regard yet. Maybe I am just using not the right keywords.

Any help is highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You'll need to show the code of the "alter" button (and other relevant code, if applicable). Otherwise it's impossible to help you.

Comment: If user is allowed to unlock a form at will, why bother locking to begin with?

Comment: @June7 - I've done that before because they wanted to eliminate accidental edits

Comment: Is the field the last one on the form? Do you have the Form property `Other | Cycle` set to `All Records` - if so, change to `Current Record` - perhaps it is cycling to next record after enter

Comment: @Andre there isn't really much code to show. I mean I have just one function which is called when the button is clicked and the first thing I am doing is changing the field "Last User" to the current User and as soon as I change it, the dataset switches.

Comment: @June7 Because I want to prevent accidental edits, just like dbmitch says.

Comment: @dbmitch The field is indeed the last on the form. I will check that, even though the ID jumps from like 170000 to 40000, which would be weird if that's the 'next' record.

Comment: @dbmitch The property was indeed set to All Records. I changed just like you said. I will have to see if the error occurs again. The strange thing is also that this error does not occur everytime I press the button. I could not reliably reproduce it.